# Painless Kinana scripted field: how to extract some specific chars from a text field starting at a certain position

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-painless

I usually use the Excel function MID() (i.e. `=MID(A1,9,3)` if I want to extract three consecutive characters from the string in A1, starting at the 9th posiotion). How can I do it in Painless?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the substring function.

Given this string : XXXXXXXX**YYY**XXXXXXX

If we want to extract **YYY** (Three characters from position 9th) :

`ctx.extracted_field = ctx.og_field.substring(8, 11);`

This will capture from position 8 to 11, position starts from 0.

Ideally you want to have this indexed , one way to get it ingested is using an ingest pipeline:

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/substring
{
  "description": "Emulates Excel =MID(A1,9,3) function",
  "processors": [
    {
      "script": {
        "source": "ctx.extracted_field = ctx.og_field.substring(8, 11);"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Ingest pipelines documentation:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html

Comment: Thanks. I tried something similar but it returns an error. Tried def ctx.extracted_field = doc['og_field'].value; return ctx.extracted_field.substring(8, 11) ; In that field there are also some strings with less than 5 chars and maybe that is the reason why I get some errors

Comment: that's a good guess. In that case you have to validate the field is a good candidate using the length function = if(doc['og_field'].length() > 8) { //substrcode// }